# How to parse an XML file using Nokogiri and Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a XML file:

```
<root>
    <person name="brother">Abhijeet</person>
    <person name="sister">pratiksha</person>
</root>
```

I want it to parse using Nokogiri. I tried by using CSS and XPath but it returns nil or the first element value. How do I retrieve other values?
I tried:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xmlFile)
doc.elements.each do |f|
    f.each do |y|
         p y
    end
end
```

and:

```
doc.xpath("//person/sister")
doc.at_xpath("//person/sister")
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Have you read the Nokogiri tutorials? They discuss how to search and extract information. Have you searched the internet for how to find a node's parameter based on the value? Your selector isn't correct so searching will explain what to do. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 is important too.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic way to search for a node with a given parameter and value using CSS:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<root>
  <person name="brother">Abhijeet</person>
  <person name="sister">pratiksha</person>
</root>
EOT

doc.at('person[name="sister"]').to_html # => "<person name=\"sister\">pratiksha</person>"
```

You need to research CSS and XPath and how their syntax work. In XPath `//person/sister` means search everywhere for `<sister>` nodes inside `<person>` nodes, matching something like:

```
<root>
  <person>
    <sister />
  </person>
  <person>
    <sister />
  </person>
</root>
```

Where it would find all the `<sister />` nodes. It doesn't search for the parameter of a node.

Don't do:

```
doc.elements.each do |f|
    f.each do |y|
         p y
    end
end
```

You're going to waste a lot of CPU walking through every element. Instead learn how selectors work, so you can take advantage of the power of libXML.